# Few confusing things about passing references to non-root entities to external objects

Tags: domain-driven-design

*Root entity* can pass *transient references to internal entities* to *external objects*, but under the condition that *external objects* don't hold on to that reference after an operation is completed

1)

a) Why is it acceptable for *external object* having a reference ( to an *internal entity* ) for the duration of a single operation, but not acceptable for it to hold on to that reference for a duration of two operations?  My point being, if it's bad to hold on to a reference for the duration of two operations, then it's probably equally bad to hold on to it for a duration of a single operation?!

b) Assuming `SomeRootEnt` *Aggregate root* passes *transient reference of internal entity* `SomeIntEnt` to *external object*, how should *external object* request `SomeIntEnt`? By invoking a particular method on a *root* – e.g. `SomeRootEnt.BorrowMeIntEnt(...)` - or should *root* directly expose *internal entity* as its *property* ( e.g. `SomeRootEnt.SomeIntEnt` )?

2)

a) Assuming `SomeRootEnt` *root* passes a reference to *internal entity* `SomeIntEnt`  to *external object*, which in turn makes some modifications on `SomeIntEnt`, then doesn't this mean that *root* has no way of applying the appropriate *invariant logic* on those modifications ( ie *root* can't check for the integrity of modified `SomeIntEnt`?

b) Similarly, to my understanding at least, *root* also has no way to force the *external object* to drop a reference to *internal entity* after the completion of a single operation?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

2a)

> That is correct, which is why it is best to ensure that the passed
>   object isn't modified, but is used in an immutable way. Moreover, the
>   passed entity can still maintain a degree of integrity on its own.

Would it be primarily the responsibility of *Aggregate root* (and partly by passed *entity*) or of an *external object* ( which receives the *transient reference* ) to ensure that passed *entity* isn't modified? If the latter, then isn't the consistency of this aggregate really at the mercy of whoever developed the *external object*?

2b)

> Correct and it is your responsibility to ensure this. Just like you
>   have to ensure that a give value object is immutable (if needed) you
>   have to consider the integrity of passed references.

I assume in most cases it would be the responsibility of *external object* to get rid of the reference as soon as an operation is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1a) A reference to an entity may be needed to support a domain operation, however that reference should be transient in that it isn't held after the operation. It is only held only for the duration of the operation, not after it and therefore it does not follow by induction that it can hold for two operations. The point of this is to ensure that the aggregate, which passed the reference to an external entity, can maintain control of its constituents. You don't want its internal entities to be taken over by some other aggregate because then it is more difficult to reason about behavior.

1b) It can go either way, depending on the use case. A property is just a method in disguise.

2a) That is correct, which is why it is best to ensure that the passed object isn't modified, but is used in an immutable way. Moreover, the passed entity can still maintain a degree of integrity on its own.

2b) Correct and it is your responsibility to ensure this. Just like you have to ensure that a give value object is immutable (if needed) you have to consider the integrity of passed references.

Most of this is a general guideline because it results in a "well-behaved", easy to reason about, and easy to make consistent aggregates.

**UPDATE**

2a) Given the limitations of programming languages, there are limits to how well an aggregate can protect itself. As a result, "human intervention" is required, especially in more complicated scenarios like this one. It is true that the aggregate may come to be at the mercy of another, which is why these guidelines are in place.

2b) Yes. The external object can make use of an internal entity of another aggregate, however it reference should be transient - meaning that it is not persisted.

Comment: uhm, it seems I've mistakenly updated your post - I apologize

Answer (score 0):

If an object with a private entity acquires a lock, passes a reference to that entity to an outside method which is never allowed to copy it to any location that will still *exist* after that method leaves scope, and then releases the lock, it can be sure that when the lock is released, no outside entity will hold a reference.  That invariant will hold even if code somewhere within the lock throws an exception.  If an outside method is allowed to store a reference to an entity anywhere that might outlive it, even if it promises that some other action will destroy that reference, it becomes much harder to ensure that the action necessary to destroy the outside reference will actually occur before the lock is released.